# JAVA: Why do I need to create a new list object in this function?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

**Edit:**

The function is part of an answer to lintcode question "combination sum", if I use the second version, the output is "[[],...,[]], where all inner list is empty, even when they are passed in with values. When I just switch to the first version without changing anything else, it would work.

So I assume it has something to with the Java parameter-passing process that I don't understand. Could you please explain why only the first version can work?

**Code:**

```
private void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> list, int target, ...) {
    if (target == 0) {
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));

        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Question:**

Why do I need to create a new *ArrayList* object and then add it to *result*?

What's the difference between this method and the code below:

```
private void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> list, int target, ...) {
    if (target == 0) {
        result.add(list);

        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

Could someone explain this to me? Thank you!

Comment: The difference is exactly what you stated. Either you're creating a new list, or you're using the existing list. What's the intent of this function?

Comment: The intent is to add "list" to "result", the function is part of the answer to a lintcode question. However, when I use the second version, the output is [[], ..., []], basically all inner list is empty. If I switch to the first one, it would work. That's why I'm kind of confused

Comment: Could you provide your implementation of the solution to the combination sum problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new ArrayList object by passing an existing list to the constructor the Integers contained in the list are *copied* to that new list.

If the list instead is just added to the result and is modified afterwards by e.g. adding or removing elements the modifications are reflected in the result which may or may not be intended, depending on context.

The difference becomes obvious when running this code:

```
private static void helper1(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    // add by duplicating the provided list
    result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
}

private static void helper2(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    // add provided list as is
    result.add(list);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(10);
    helper1(result, list1);

    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(20);
    helper2(result, list2);

    System.out.println(result); // [[10], [20]]

    list1.add(11);
    list2.add(21);

    System.out.println(result); // [[10], [20, 21]]
}
```

Here, first two list are added to the result each containing one Integer. The first list is added using helper1 and the second list is added using helper2. After that both lists are modified by adding another Integer. For list1 the change doesn't have any effect on our result but the modification of list2 does.

Comment: Thank you！This is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, they're doing the same thing, however, the only difference I can notice is the first one uses more memory and there is no need to actually construct a new ArrayList of an already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you don´t really use the given value, instead you create a new local List. 
In the second example do you work with the given value.

For example, if you call the method and give as value of `ArrayList<Integer>list` `[2,5,52,888]`  ,so you´ll add the value to the existing List.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example if the list is changed outside the method the list in the result changed too since it's same instance of list.

In the first example you create a copy of the list isolating it from modifications.

Answer (score 0):

@CollinD raised a good question as to make sure you know the true intent of the helper method.

When you pass in an object in Java you're passing in a reference to the object. Any changes to the reference will be reflected in the original object you created.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    helper(arrays, list1);
    arrays.get(0).add(3);

    list1.forEach(e -> System.out.print(e));
    System.out.print("\n");
    arrays.get(0).forEach(e-> System.out.print(e));

}
```

Try executing this example code with the two different helper methods.

What you'll notice is that the original method will provide you with two different lists of values.

```
12
123
```

While the second method provides you with the same values

```
123
123
```

This is because the constructor of ArrayList(list) does a copy of the values in list to a new object. The second method simple adds the reference lists to the array to be used later which in the example project I gave, you now have two different ways to access list1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It's really helpful!